# How do i iterate through JSON in VueJS?

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am storing some settings in the database with keys and JSON data but when I get these settings from a Laravel API, it returns an array which becomes a hectic work in reassigning data to the input fields. I want to know if there is an easier way of doing it.

So far I have tried iterating and using the switch statement to identify keys and reassign them. But the problem is I can't access the VueJS data variable in the loop.

Here is a look at the database table:
[Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXke8.png)

Here are the objects I am using in Vue:

```
    helpful_notification: {
        email: false,
        sms: false,
        push: false,
    },
    updates_newsletter: {

          email: false,
          sms: false,
          push: false,

    },
```

Here is my Code to Iterate over results:

```
   axios.get('/api/notificationsettings')
      .then(response => {
          var data = response.data;
          let list = [];
          console.log(data)
          $.each(data, function(i, j){
            switch(j.key){
              case 'transactional': 

                  var settings = JSON.parse(j.settings)
                  var x = {
                  transactional : settings
                }
                list.push(x)
              break;
              case 'task_reminder': 
                 var settings = JSON.parse(j.settings)
                  x = {
                  task_reminder : settings
                }
                list.push(x)
                break; 
            }
          });
          this.transactional = list;
          // this.task_reminder= list.task_reminder;
          console.log(list);
      })
      .catch(error => {

      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) have their own [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope), save for a few exceptions. Which means that, inside your anonymous function (i.e:

```
 $.each(data, function(i, j){
   // this here is the function scope, not the outside scope
 })
```

...), `this` is not the outside scope, it's the function's scope

There are two ways to make the outside scope available inside your function:

**a) place it inside a variable**

```
 const _this = this;
 $.each(data, function(i, j){
   // this is function scope, 
   // _this is outside scope (i.e: _this.list.task_reminder)
 })
```

**b) use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions)**

```
$.each(data, (i, j) => {
   // this is the outside scope
   // the arrow function doesn't have a scope. 
})
```

The above is a simplification aimed at helping you access the outside scope inside your function. But `this` can differ based on the context it is used in. You can read more about `this` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).